# C# Refactor code to make re-usable with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

This is a very loaded question but I am new to using generics and want to become proficient using them and taking my C#/.NET skills to the next level. I created a data filter using multiple dropdowns. Before I break the below method into smaller encapsulated, single responsibility methods, I was hoping I could get some help.

My goal is to re-use this filter in many parts of our application. In order to do so I will have to add the "filter" methods to our common base EntityController and EntityRespository classes. Obviously I am going to have to make use of generics to accomplish this task. Can anyone give me some advice after looking at the below (ridiculously long) method?

```
        [HttpPost("FilteredResults")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PaginatedList<ProcessCard>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredBusinessProcesses([FromBody] List<FieldFilterCriteria> filterCriteriaList = null)
        {
            try
            {
                List<BusinessProcess> listOfCommonItems = new List<BusinessProcess>();
                PaginatedList<BusinessProcess> paginatedListOfCommonItems = new PaginatedList<BusinessProcess>();
                var orgIdGuid = filterCriteriaList[0]?.OrganizationId;

                if (filterCriteriaList != null)
                {
                    var results = repository.Find(null, a => a.OrganizationId == orgIdGuid);

                    foreach (FieldFilterCriteria filter in filterCriteriaList)
                    {
                        foreach (string value in filter?.FilterValues)
                        {
                            switch (filter.Field)
                            {
                                case "Department":
                                    var dList = results?.Items.Where(x => x.OrganizationUnitId == Guid.Parse(value)).ToList();
                                    listOfCommonItems.AddRange(dList);
                                    break;
                                case "Status":
                                    var sList = results?.Items.Where(x => x.Status == value).ToList();
                                    listOfCommonItems.AddRange(sList);
                                    break;
                                case "Priority":
                                    var pList = results?.Items.Where(x => x.Priority == value).ToList();
                                    listOfCommonItems.AddRange(pList);
                                    break;
                                case "Owner":
                                    var oList = results?.Items.Where(x => x.OwnerName == value).ToList();
                                    listOfCommonItems.AddRange(oList);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (filterCriteriaList.Count == 1)
                    {
                        paginatedListOfCommonItems.Items = listOfCommonItems;
                    }

                    if (filterCriteriaList.Count > 1)
                    {
                        listOfCommonItems = listOfCommonItems.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
                        paginatedListOfCommonItems.Items = listOfCommonItems;
                    }

                    var businessProcessCard = processCatalogManager.GetBusinessProcessCard(paginatedListOfCommonItems);

                    return Ok(businessProcessCard);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.GetActionResult();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think the bigger issue, instead of generics, should be you worrying about making your controllers "skinny".  All this logic you have in the action should be in a service that is injected in as a dependency

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of headache if you refactor to smaller more testable methods before trying to implement generics. Its a lot easier to fix 3 small methods than it is to fix 1 giant method that is failing in 3 areas.

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought I did a better job explaining. I already have a service for this controller class. I am going to use Resharper's refactor tool to break them up into smaller methods. We (and I think most folks) do not keep any logic in our controllers. This was just my first pass at getting a working example. it will be broken down into 3 smaller methods, however, I wanted you to see it in its entirety instead of me posting multiple encapsulated, single responsibility methods for you to sift through. I hope this clarifies my intent.

Comment: Anyone with any advice?